# Google maps V2 marker's title in other languages

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show a marker on Google Maps API V2:

this is my code:

```
driverMarker = new MarkerOptions();
driverMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.driver_car));
driverMarker.position(driverLocation);
driverMarker.title(getDriver().getName());
googleMap.addMarker(driverMarker);
```

The driver name is saved in Hebrew, and also my Google maps language is in Hebrew (the street names). However, when my getDriver().getName() returns string in Hebrew it doesn't show me the title (the title is blank as you can see in the screenshot attached). But if the poi.getName() returns string in english it show the title on the marker...

What can I do in order to display Hebrew on the marker's title???

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhJPS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution here by @Gavriel:
[Non-ASCII title for android map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244298/non-ascii-title-for-android-map-marker)

In short:
You can use `android:textDirection="locale"` on `TextView` in customized `InfoWindowAdapter` (if you are using api 17 and higher)

or
Prepend an unicode left-to-right mark to the title/snippet:

```
.title("\u200e" + titleText)
.snippet("\u200e" + snippetText)
```